# Batch file that kills a certain process

Tags: windows, batch-file, kill-process

I am using the following script to kill a process in CLOSE_WAIT state that listens to a certain ip and to a certain port.

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%I IN (
    'netstat -ano ^| find "127.0.0.1:5900" ^| find "CLOSE_WAIT"'
) DO (
    taskkill /PID %%I
)
```

The script does it's job but I am looking for a small modification.

I would like the process to be killed only if there are more than 10 connections into CLOSE_WAIT state. If let's say there are only 3 connections in CLOSE_WAIT then the process shouldn't be killed.

Comment: Funny, I just tried your command (changing the taskill line to an `echo %%I`) on a Vista computer and I got a "Running low on memory error" from Windows. I quickly went into Process Explorer and saw that cmd.exe had multiplied itself dozens of times. I nuked that entire process tree and everything calmed down. But I wonder what happened...? Do you get multiple cmd.exe processes from that cycle?

Comment: I am using this on windows 2008 and no, I only get one cmd window that closes as soon as it checks for CLOSE_WAIT so no problems on my side, except the modification I would like to have

Comment: Upon further tests I believe the problem happens when netstat returns nothing matching those criteria. I don't have connections for 127.0.0.1:5900, and I get the problem. If I search for 10.0.0.128 (I have connections there) it works fine. By the way, don't test a criteria that doesn't return anything, unless you make sure you save your work first, as this could get complicated... and make sure you have a task manager that can kill entire Process trees (a process and everything it spawned) in just one go.

Comment: The script works fine for my needs. I only need an addition something like an IF case that should kill the process only if the script finds more than 10 connections in CLOSE_WAIT but I have no idea what would be the command for this.

Comment: I got it now. I had previously named my own script netstat.cmd. That was a silly thing to do, it was calling itself infinitely. Sorry for that confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt.

I used a few tricks from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913231/how-do-i-increment-a-dos-variable-in-a-for-f-loop

```
echo off

set /a c=1
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%I IN (
    'netstat -ano ^| find "127.0.0.1:5900" ^| find "CLOSE_WAIT"'
) DO (
    set /a c=c+1
    set /a last=%%I
)
if %c% geq 10 (
   taskkill /PID !last!
)

endlocal
```

Basically, during the cycle I just increment a variable. In the end, if the count is greater than 10, I kill the task.

Limitation: this only counts lines returned by the `netstat` and `finds`, and uses **the last PID counted** for the taskkill. It assumes all the lines are from the same PID, but this is only true in some cases (like your case, where you search for address **and port**).

Comment: I've changed to 1 and 2 connections for test purpose but doesn't seem to kill the process.

Comment: Inside the final IF try adding `echo !c!` and `echo !last!` to see what the variables are when you get there. I am not 100% sure when to use %c% or !c!, so I could have a bug there. But it worked in my tests...

Comment: (Make sure you're using my edited version of the batch file, not the first one I posted. The only difference is the criteria for the first `find`)

Comment: I think I was testing it wrong. Works fine now, going to test it for a day or two when my application gets into the specified connection state. Thank a lot for your help, @pgr. Will get back and mark the answer if everything turns to be alright.